# How can I do a pseudocode in a powerdot presentation?

Tags: presentations, powerdot

I'm trying to write a pseudocode in a powerdot presentation. I used the commands `\usepackage{algorithm}` and `\usepackage{algorithmic}`, but they didn't work. Which package or what can I do to write a pseudocode in a powerdot presentation?

Comment: show in an example that it didn't work what you tried.

Comment: With no additional information this is 'too localised'.